# Do any scriptures say that Varna is determined by Rashi?

Tags: identification-request, astrology, varna, rashi

Many people say that Varna is determined by birth, and others say Varna is determined by qualities.  But I've seen some websites which claim that Varna is based on Rashi(our birth constellation/star).  My question is, are there any scriptures which claim that Varna is determined by Rashi?

Comment: You mean the one that is found in our horoscopes?

Comment: @Rickross Yes, by horoscope

Comment: Everything has a varna which are in reality gunas: Nirguna(Brahmin), Satva(Kshatriya), Rajas(Vaishya) and Tamas(Shudra), even planets themselves have a varna as explained in BPHS. http://jyotishvidya.com/ch3.htm "21. PLANETARY CASTES: Jupiter and Venus are Brahmins. The Sun is a royal planet while the Moon and Mercury belong to commercial community. Saturn rules the Sudra (4th caste)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Varna koota is factor in Vedic astrology which is used for match making purpose.

Four signs each are divided into 4 categories of a varna each.

Totally there are 8 such factors to be considered during match making which is called as Ashta Bhakoota.

There is also another section which is called "yoni" under which people are classified under yonis such as mooshaka, mahisha, sarpa, ashwa etc. Now this does not mean that the person will have characteristics like these animals. But it is just a classification for ascertaining the compatibility between two birth charts.

There are several factors used for this which includes graha maitri, nadi, vashya etc.

So one should not confuse this Varna with the actual varna of the person.

[Source](http://www.saravali.de/articles/astakoota.html)

If this is to be considered then all those who are of libra, gemini, and aquarius sign are shudras irrespective of where they are born! Further, nowehere they consider the rashi during the upanayana ceremony for deciding the eligibility of the candidate.

Some of the famous examples of great saints who were born in these rashi are,

Sri Ramakrishna Paramahansa (Aquarius moon sign)

Ramanuja acharya (Gemini moon sign)

So this is just for matchmaking purpose and has NOTHING TO DO WITH THE ACTUAL VARNA.

Comment: Can you please provide any scriptural statement denying the relation between them?

You did mention two people: Sri Ramakrishna Paramahansa, Ramanuja acharya as an example to show that astrological varnas are not same as the varnas by birth.

It implies that, if both types varnas are same, then they both fall in to Shudras and my doubt is that why they can't be Shudras? Did it mentioned anywhere that they both are not Shudras based on their birth? or any mention that Shudras can't be liberated etc.,?

Comment: @hanugm until one gets thread samskara by default shudra.

Comment: I'm confused whether you are sure that   **NOTHING TO DO WITH THE ACTUAL VARNA** according to the scriptures or your strong opinion!

Comment: @hanugm as per astrology you will classified into a yoni for example a mouse or a cat or monkey etc. And a gana for example deva . Rakshasha or manushya. Also a varna like shudra or brahmin etc. These are for classification purpose and compatibility matching

Comment: So, you are saying that the diffrerence between astrological Varnas and Varnas told by Krishna is implicit. And it is such implicit that scriptures didn't either support or reject it.!

Comment: @hanugm this is purely astrology based thing. Its better not to complicate with other things. Can have discussion elsewhere on this.

Answer (score 6):

According to Vedic astrology the varna is determined by the chandra rasis. Or it depends on where the moon was placed during the time of birth of a native.

There are four varnas- Brahmin, Kshatriya, Vaishya and Shudra.

Different natives, depending on the moon's placement in their natal charts, are assigned one of these four varnas as follows:

> **Varna** -------> **Moon signs**
>
> Brahmin ------>            Cancer, Scorpio, Pisces.
>
> Kshatriya  -------->          Aries, Leo, Sagitarius.
>
> Vaishya ---------->             Taurus, Virgo, Capricon.
>
> Shudra  ----------->           Gemini, Libra, Aquarius.

The [Brihat Parashara Hora Shastra](http://www.astrojyoti.com/bphspage1.htm) mentions this as follows:

> [image]
>
> .....
>
> AQUARIUS DESCRIBED .' The sign Aquarius represents a man holding a
>   pot. Its complexion is deep-brown. It has a medium build and a biped
>   sign. It is very strong in day time. It resorts to deep water and is
>   airy. It rises with its head **and is Tamasic. It rules Sudras,the 4th
>   Varna** and the west. Its lord is Saturn,the Sun's offspring.
>
> [image]
>
> ..........
>
> LIBRA AND SCORPIO DESCRIBED : Libra is a Seershodaya sign rising with
>   its head and is strong in day time. It is black in complexion and is
>   predominant with RaJoguna. It relates to tho western direction and
>   resorts to land. It is destructive or mischievous. **It represents
>   Sudras or the 4th Varna** and has a medium build and is a biped sign.
>   Its lord is Venus. Scorpio has a slender physique and is a centipede
>   sign. **It denotes Brahmins** and resides in holes. Its direction is
>   north and is strong in day time. It is reddish-brown and resorts to
>   water and land. It has a hairy physique and is very sharp(or
>   passionate). Mars is its ruler.

And, so on for the other rashis.

Comment: These Varnas are just classification and has nothing to with the actual varna !

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Whether they have anything to do with actual varna or not was not my conern. I was simply answering OP's Q which originally was " What scriptures say varna is determined by rashi?" Then the answer to it is the Jyotisha scriptures like i have mentioned.

Comment: please see the first line of the question. He is asking if its determined by birth or rashi etc. further, can you cite any reference where the varna of a person was decided based on chart?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Well, there is a varna (actual or otherwise as per you) that the horoscopes determine. And i simply mentioned how to determine that. And also mentioned which scriptures talk about such classifications.

Comment: you are happy to accept Ramakrishnas varna as per his rashi?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I would not like to comment anything on that.

Comment: Can someone's varna based on birth be different from this astrological varna? Wonder what that means!

Comment: Yes it can be so. For e.g Sri Ramakrishna was a Brahmin by birth but not so by these calculations. Deep down they do mean something. @sv. It's actually describing the traits of that Rashi. Just like the Rashi influences in building the traits of the native there are other factors that contribute too. So, IMO, the determination of the native's traits will depend on many other factors and which may be better represented overall by his birth varna than his Rashi varna.

Comment: Wow brilliant answer !