# Astrological signs and śūdra-like nature

Tags: caste-system, astrology, varna, gunas, shudra

According to [this answer](https://www.quora.com/Who-were-referred-as-Shudras-in-India-How-they-were-Casted/answer/Rami-Sivan) on Quora.com:

> In the astrological context, which determines a person’s character, everyone born under the rising signs (lagna) of Gemini, Libra and Aquarius is characterized as Shudra. A Shudra in this context is one who is content to work for others, has little ambition, is subjected to passions, lacks an efficient method of self-control and primarily follows their biological programming of self-preservation and self-propagation.

Is the same mentioned in any jyotiṣa-related scripture?

Comment: Yes the BPHS mentions those classifications. See my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18960/4732)

Comment: So Astrology based casteism is 3rd caste model!  