# What is the correct way to recognize varna by astrology?

Tags: astrology, varna, pramana

Most northern Indian astrologers define varna by the sign of the zodiac occupied by the Moon.

Most South Indian astrologers define varna by the nakshatra occupied by the Moon.

And what is the technique for determining varna prescribed in the classical texts of Jyotish?

Comment: See this -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18960/4732

Comment: He answers there that varna is determined by the sign of the zodiac occupied by the Moon. But he quotes from the BPHS about ascending signs (Lagnas), and not at all lunar ones. Therefore, there is no normal answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

varna cannot be determined by nakshatra, varna determination has a unique method  of determination.
Varna is neither determined by Nakshatra nor by lagna nor by 10th lord nor by Amatyakaraka nor by lord of nakshatra or lord of lagna

Please be clear on what does not determine varna.

For determining Varna, there is a varna calculation which you can google

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).